# CakePHP - saving to more than two models using save associated

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying something more complicated. I have an Item which stores all general items, I have a Product which is an item and I have a Good which is a product and a item. So I have a form for entering value for the good and it shall save to all model related tables (items, products, goods). The reason for so many tables is because all tables shall have an id which is used later, example: product shall have its id which is used later for selling. Here is the controller:

```
public function add() {
    $this->load();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

$this->Item->create();
        $this->request->data['Item']['code'] = $finalCode;
        $this->request->data['Item']['is_deleted'] = false;
        $item = $this->Item->save($this->request->data);

        if(!empty($item)){
            $this->request->data['Product']['item_id'] = $this->Item->id;
            $this->request->data['Good']['item_id'] = $this->Item->id;

            debug($this->request->data['Product']['item_id']);
            debug($item);

            $this->Item->Product->save($this->request->data);
            $this->request->data['Good']['pid'] = $this->Product->id;
            $this->Item->Good->save($this->request->data);
        }

        if($this->Good->validationErrors || $this->Item->validationErrors || $this->Product->validationErrors){
            //ERRORS
        }
        else{
            //FAILS
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have changed the controller and now the Item is never saved but Product and Good is saved and they are all mapped well, ids are ok but Item is not even in the db, althrough Product and Good have item_id set to a value which should be next in the db.

```
class Good extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        ),
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'pid',
        )
    );
}

class Product extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Good' => array(
            'className' => 'Good',
            'foreignKey' => 'pid',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
    );
}

class Item extends AppModel{

    public $hasMany = array(
         'Good' => array(
        'className' => 'Good',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
    );

}
```

Even the debugged $item looks ok but is not saved:

```
array(
    'Item' => array(
        'name' => 'Microcontrollers',
        'description' => 'Wire Jumpers Female-to-Female 30 cm',
        'weight' => '22',
        'measurement_unit_id' => '7',
        'item_type_id' => '29',
        'code' => 'GOD-34',
        'is_deleted' => false,
        'modified' => '2019-10-22 12:37:53',
        'created' => '2019-10-22 12:37:53',
        'id' => '120'
    ),
    'Good' => array(
        'status' => 'development',
        'hts_number' => '8473 30 20',
        'tax_group' => '20%',
        'eccn' => 'EAR99',
        'release_date' => array(
            'month' => '10',
            'day' => '22',
            'year' => '2019',
            'hour' => '10',
            'min' => '10',
            'meridian' => 'am'
        ),
        'is_for_distributors' => '1'
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'project' => 'neqwww'
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to associate a `Product` with a `Good` as well as an `Item`? There's not generally something wrong with that, but CakePHP can't handle that automatically, it can only save associations in one direction, that is parents or children, what you're trying is saving a sibling dataset so to speak. The stupid data structure requirement of CakePHP 2.x can be a little distracting, but basically `Item` isn't nested in `Product`, and that won't work. You'd have to manually issue multiple save's and provide the foreign keys accordingly.

Comment: Well, I am not quite sure. So what you are trying to say is that it cannot be done via a one transaction. If I would do it other way, I could simply first save an Item than save other to and access the items id since it is saved. But I am not sure it is good if it is not done in one transaction. Problem is, maybe the database design is flawed in itself. But I have a project with fixed organization and I cannot find better design. It is demanded that all products have a unique id, and since products can be goods, services etc, the only unique id they will have is in Items, so maybe that is ok.

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to simply drop products table since it seems quite redundant.

Comment: Well, I can't really give you any advise on that, it's hard to tell without knowing about the full picture. But note that you can manually issue transactions: **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html**. `$this` is a model instance in that case, and you'd need to set the `atomic` option to `false` in your save calls: **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your code at the lines where you are saving the data.

```
$this->Item->create();
$this->Good->create();
$this->Product->create();
```

What is $this? If you create a item with "$this" and later try to create a "product", "$this" will not have the item_id.

Try using something like this to save the item created.

```
$item = $this->Item->create();
```

Then, with that $item created, you could create a $product with the $item->id

Update:

From cakephp documentation.

```
// Create: id isn't set or is null
$this->Recipe->create();
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);

// Update: id is set to a numerical value
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);
```

You must use $this->Item->save($data) to save the information into database.

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Maybe the method create() is a bit unclear. It is used to restart the model state.

So, it would be

```
$item_saved = $this->Item->save($data['Item']);
$data['Product']['item_id'] = $this->Item->getLastInsertId();
$product_saved = $this->Product->save($data['Product']);
```

Edit 2:

Maybe it is because you didn't use create() before save the Item. Try this please:

```
$this->Item->create();
$item_saved = $this->Item->save($data['Item']);
$data['Product']['item_id'] = $this->Item->getLastInsertId();
$product_saved = $this->Product->save($data['Product']);
```

Comment: But CakePHP should connect those ids by itself since model has all the relations. Even when I try to set $item = $this->Item->create(); and later to debug its value, it returns an empty array. Your solution does not work, since $item is not an object since Model::create() does not return the saved object, it just resets current model to its default. I could access the data with $this->data which returns correct data to be inserted and then id with $this->data['Product']['item_id'] but I do not have a value to set it to. How can I access an id of the object to be inserted before it is saved.

Comment: Also, $this->Item->id is accessible only after the save is completed, but I cannot do that, since I should save them all in one transaction.

Comment: @МладенКарић I edited my answer, maybe now it is useful for you

Comment: It is a good direction, although now Good and Product is saved, but Item is not, I have updated the question.